# Уведомления для мобильного приложения об изменениях базы данных

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, signalr, webapi

Дана следующая структура. 
Есть партиционированная(секционированная) база данных (MSSQL), слой сервисов (C# web-api или WCF), мобильный клиент (IOS).
Цель организовать уведомление мобильных клиентов что один из них внес изменения в базу. 
Насколько я знаю для этого можно использовать MS Service Broker, при изменении таблицы будет подниматься событие. В сервисах его можно перехватывать через объект SqlDependency, подписанный на конкретный запрос (поправьте, если я не прав).
И так несколько вопросов:

1. Есть ли возможность настройки Service Broker-а на уведомления об изменении конкретной партиции (в реалиях MSSQL при партиционированнии базы, под каждую партицию создается свой файл и файловая группа).
2. Как организовать уведомление клиентов. До этого реализовывал приложения в реальном времени с помощью SignalR, но клиент был на JS и там была возможность подписаться на конкретный hub. Что делать в случаи IOS приложения?
   Мобильные разработчики настаивают на варианте long polling. 
   В моем случае предполагаю что надо будет захватить GET запрос на таймер и путем while loop ждать пока не поднимется событие SqlDependency (правильный ли это подход?). 
   Но long polling захватывает потоки и не отпускает пока не будет получен ответ (верное ли предположение). Таким образом уже при количестве клиентов больше 1000 будет захвачено 1000 потоков, на достаточно серьезный срок.
   Хорошим ли для этого случая является вариант WebSocket-а?
3. Возможно ли для такого случая использовать реализацию AMQP (RabbitMQ или ZeroMQ)? Вместо интеграции через базу данных. 
   В следующей структуре. Устройство присылает POST запрос и обновляет
   данные в указанной партиции, затем при успешном апдейте помещает в
   очередь сообщение с нужным заголовком, и все подписчики получают
   уведомление, затем отправляя GET запрос на получение данных.

Заранее спасибо за внимание и помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уведомления через Service Broker - достаточно хрупкое и громоздкое, и нестабильное решение. Мне приходилось поддерживать систему, где нотификации были организованы через вызов .net кода в SB - это настоящий ад.

SqlDependency приспособлен прежде всего для инвализации кэша, а не для полноценного получения Callback-ов.

Самым простым и стабильным решением (по моему опыту), является следующее:

- мобильные клиенты при старте приложения присылают на сервер токен Apple Push Notifications Service.
- код, обрабатывающий изменения сохраняет из в базу данныз, и после этого отправляет нотификацию в очередь (Service Bus, RabbitMQ или что-то еще с AMQP протоколом)
- фоновый обработчик (Windows Service, Azure Web Job, или даже Azure Function с триггером на AMQP) вычитывает сообщения из очереди, и рассылает уведомления клиентам через APNS.
- мобильные клиенты обрабатывают push-нотификации и или берут нужные данные прямо из payload, или лезут за ними на сервер по получению нотификации.

Такая схема легко масштабируется

- в ней не требуется постоянного подключения к вашему серверу со стороны мобильников.
- для каждого мобильника нужно всего-лишь сохранить токен. Не нужно ни держать поток, ни обрабатывать обрывы соединений.
- обработка регистрации, отправка нотификаций, и обработка изменений слабо связаны друг с другом и могут быть разнесены по разным приложениям (с независимым деплойментом).

Comment: Большое спасибо. В целом так и приступил к реализации. Пока есть мучения с установкой на Win10 RabbitMQ (на Win8 все встало без проблем). В ближайшее время попробую установить сразу на WinServer 2012R.

Comment: @TimRiazanovt проще всего поднять в контейнере через docker: https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/